# Recover tomcat7 shutdown.sh file contents

Tags: java, linux, tomcat7

I mistakingly typed `cat > shutdown.sh` in tomcat's bin folder(`/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/bin`) there by deleting it totally and replacing it with new blank file.

How do I recover it or where do I find the contents of this shutdown.sh so that I may copy and paste it there?

Comment: Here you can download your tomcat version http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/

Comment: @RenéLink thanks! I see lots of files in that link under the tomcat version of my choice(like .zip/.tar.gz etc.). Will all of them have same contents in shutdown.sh?

Comment: Download this one http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.55/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.55.zip. You will find the `shutdown.sh` in the `apache-tomcat-7.0.55\bin` folder.

Comment: @RenéLink your "Link" works :D